# IntelliJ - easy way to add all environment variables and PATH locations to the run config

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14, intellij-13, intellij-15

We can add Environment variables one by one environment variables manually using UI screen. But is there a easy way to load/add all PATH locations or Environment variables mentioned in .bashrc file.

[image]

Comment: Did you try https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile? Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes all you need to do is paste them in the Run/Debug Configuration screen before this window opens. Each env variable must be deliminated by a semicolon `;` too.

Example:

```
PATH=/mypath; JAVA_HOME=/anotherpath;
```

Intellij Guide:

[image]

Paste them here:

[image]

Comment: How to make sure these env variables are available to all the git branches? If we add env variables to the master branch and then create a release/feature branch then it is available. However, if we add any new env variable in the feature branch and then checkout the master branch then that variable is not available in the run configuration. 

In other words Its works downward git branch streams but not the other way.